# Not sure if my String code is case sensitive

Tags: java

I keep getting the incorrect answer to how many lines contain the text. I believe my code is ignoring punctuation (e.g. it won't detect the) and upper-case variations like (The).

For Example, if a file contains 5268 lines, and 1137 of those lines contain the word "the", my code returns output saying it only contains 1032 of those lines contain the word "the".

Thank you. Code is Below

```
while((sentence=buffer.readLine()) != null) //Reading Content from the file till the end of file
{
    if (sentence.contains(search_word))
    {
        word_line_count++;
    }
    line_count++; //increment line count for every while loop iteration
}

System.out.println(file_name + " has " + line_count + " lines"); //printing the line count
System.out.println("Enter some text");
System.out.println( word_line_count + " line(s) contain " + "\"" + search_word + "\""); //printing the number of lines contains the given word
file_object.close(); //closing file object
```

Comment: Another thing: your code will count "then" or "brother" as examples of "the".

Answer (score 0):

Punctuation is counted, but mixed case is not. Easiest fix would be to change

```
if (sentence.contains(search_word))
```

to

```
if (sentence.toLowerCase().contains(search_word.toLowerCase()))
```

it would be even better to convert `search_word` to lowercase once before the loop.